# Weighted Wilcoxon test in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to perform a Wilcoxon test on two samples x and y where x and y are  numeric vectors of length n.

Given some experimental design, I would like to give to some entries in x some weights.
How can such weights be included in the Wilcoxon test?
I found various packages: "survey", "Hmisc"

but a simple test with no weights does not give me back the standard Wilcoxon result:
for instance:

```
x=rnorm(n=100,mean=0,sd=1)
y=rnorm(n=100,mean=0.1,sd=1)
wilcox.test(x,y)
data:  x and y 
W = 4389, p-value = 0.1358
```

with the WWest function:
    wwest(x,y)

```
Wald Test of H0: BETA1=0
TS: 0.0284 PVAL: 0.8665 

Drop Test of H0: BETA1=0
TS: 0.0406 PVAL: 0.8407
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Using (pseudo-)random numbers, repeating the above code (wilcox.test(x,y) 10'000 times, I get p values with a mean about 0.43 and sd 0.30, compatible with both 0.1358 and 0.86, but 0.13 would be only the 4th percentile, i.e. not exactly a likely result.  => may use set.seed to show reproducible results.

Comment: Hi Martin, no matter what the seed is, I would expected a _perfect_ match between the output of wwest and wilcox.test.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion of a weighted Wilcox test
x and y are the vectors to compare, wx is the vector of weights to be applied to x,

```
wwilcox = function( x, y, wx  ){

U = 0
## Loop over the selection branches
for( iy in y ){

## Neutral branches smaller or equal
smaller = which(  x < iy )
equal = which( x == iy )

## Count
sumSmaller = sum(wx[smaller])
sumEqual = sum(wx[equal]/2)
sumTot = sumSmaller + sumEqual

## Total rank
U = U + sumTot
}

## U statistics
nY = length(y)
nX = sum(wx)

## Large sample: U follows a Gaussian
mU = nY * nX / 2
sigU = sqrt( ( nY * nX * ( 1 + nY + nX ) ) / 12 )
zU = ( U - mU ) / sigU

## p-value, one-sided
pU = erfc( zU / sqrt(2) ) /2

return(pU)
}

## Complemantery error function
erfc = function(x) 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2), lower = FALSE)
```

Any comment welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion / lacking consensus what to refer as "Wilcoxon" test. In fact, This guy was quite busy and seems to have contributed to many tests.

While `WWest` seems to work as paired test (according to a glance at the code - please correct me if wrong), `wilcox.test` (with default parameters `paired=FALSE`) does *not* perform what is often referred to as (paired) Wilcoxon test (but a U-test). To get the "clasical" Wilcoxon test, use `paired=FALSE`.

Comment: I see, however I still don't get coherent outputs. I tried to implement it by myself (see my answer)