# Paired Wilcoxon test with weights in R

Tags: r, statistics, package

I would like to perform a non-parametric statistical pairwise comparison of two samples `x` and `y` using the Wilcoxon test in R, but each of the pairs have a weight associated.

Here you have an example of the data:

```
set.seed(9)

x <- sample(x = c(1:100), size = 20, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(x = c(1:100), size = 20, replace = TRUE)
weight <- runif(n = 20)

data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, weight = weight)
```

[image]

I know  Wilcoxon test (without weights) is implemented in R, e.g. wilcox.test(x,y, paired = TRUE)`. However, I'm not able to find a way to make this test with possibility to add a weight to each one of the pairs. Do you know how to make this in R?

Comment: Have you seen this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648052/weighted-wilcoxon-test-in-r

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, thank you.I'm new in statistical tests and I'm not sure if these packages fit well with my problem -I'm not working with a survival problem, for example. I also see in that post that the output without weighting is not the same using the traditional Wilcoxon test and the function in the package, so I'm not sure of using them... Any comment or advice is appreciated.