# Weighted Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test in Python

Tags: python, statistics, hypothesis-test, scipy.stats

I have some ordinal data that I want to run a Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test between two groups (say male vs female).

However, for other categories (such as age) there is some unbalancing between the population proportions and the sample that I got, therefore I wanted to apply some weights to each data point.

Using [Weighted Wilcoxon test in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648052/weighted-wilcoxon-test-in-r) as a head start, I created a code in python to do this assuming I have both weights for x and y.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erfc

def weighted_ranksum_test(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, wx: np.ndarray, wy: np.ndarray):
    U = 0
    for iy, weight_y in zip(y, wy):
        smaller = x < iy
        equal = x == iy

        sum_smaller = np.sum(wx[smaller] * weight_y)
        sum_equal = np.sum(wx[equal] * weight_y / 2)
        sum_tot = sum_smaller + sum_equal

        U += sum_tot

    nY = np.sum(wy)
    nX = np.sum(wx)

    mU = nY * nX / 2
    sigU = np.sqrt((nY * nX * (1 + nY + nX)) / 12)
    zU = (U - mU) / sigU

    pU = erfc(zU / np.sqrt(2)) / 2

    return pU
```

My question is, does this implementation look correct? I tested this against https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ranksums.html assuming equal weights, and it gets to the same p-value, but I'm not sure if this is the correct implementation for the situation I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say from a theoretical perspective, but since there are no other answers, I can give some evidence for the validity of this test (although it depends on the values of the weights) and suggest alternative.

First, as you noted, there is agreement with `scipy.stats.ranksums` in the special case of weights equal to `1.0`. For completeness:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.special import erfc

# Your function verbatim
def weighted_ranksum_test(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, wx: np.ndarray, wy: np.ndarray):
    U = 0
    for iy, weight_y in zip(y, wy):
        smaller = x < iy
        equal = x == iy

        sum_smaller = np.sum(wx[smaller] * weight_y)
        sum_equal = np.sum(wx[equal] * weight_y / 2)
        sum_tot = sum_smaller + sum_equal

        U += sum_tot

    nY = np.sum(wy)
    nX = np.sum(wx)

    mU = nY * nX / 2
    sigU = np.sqrt((nY * nX * (1 + nY + nX)) / 12)
    zU = (U - mU) / sigU

    pU = erfc(zU / np.sqrt(2)) / 2

    return pU

# Generate data and weights
m, n = 13, 17
rng = np.random.default_rng(6270910759530225579)  # arbitrary seed
x = rng.random(size=m)
y = rng.random(size=n)
wx = np.ones_like(x)
wy = np.ones_like(y)

# Compare p-value with SciPy
# Roughly, the alternative hypothesis is that observations from the distribution
# underlying `x` tend to be less than those from the distribution underlying `y`
_, res = stats.ranksums(x, y, alternative='less')
ref = weighted_ranksum_test(x, y, wx, wy)
np.testing.assert_allclose(res, ref)  # passes
```

Another property we'd expect is for integer weights to have the same effect as repeated observations.

```py
wx = rng.integers(1, 10, size=m)
wy = rng.integers(1, 10, size=n)
x2 = np.repeat(x, wx)
y2 = np.repeat(y, wy)
wx2 = np.ones_like(x2)
wy2 = np.ones_like(y2)
res = weighted_ranksum_test(x, y, wx, wy)
ref = weighted_ranksum_test(x2, y2, wx2, wy2)
np.testing.assert_allclose(res, ref)  # passes
```

Perhaps most importantly, we'd expect the p-values of the test to be uniformly distributed under the null hypothesis that all observations were drawn at random from the same population. We can assess this using a Monte Carlo approach: generate random samples under the null hypothesis, compute the p-value for each pair, and compare the empirical distribution of the p-values against the uniform distribution.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wx = rng.random(size=m)
wy = rng.random(size=n)

def assess_size():
  ps = []
  for i in range(10000):
    x = rng.random(size=m)
    y = rng.random(size=n)
    p = weighted_ranksum_test(x, y, wx, wy)
    ps.append(p)

  res = stats.ecdf(ps)  # empirical cumulative distribution object
  ax = plt.subplot()
  res.cdf.plot(ax)
  ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
  ax.set_xlabel('p-value')
  ax.set_ylabel('CDF')
  ax.set_title('Empirical distribution of p-values under H0')
  ax.legend(['ECDF', 'Uniform CDF'])
  
assess_size()
```

[image]

With uniformly distributed weights, the test has roughly the expected "size" (the probability of incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis if it is true), but it is a bit conservative; for example, fewer than 5% of the p-values are less than 0.05.

This discrepancy disappears when the weights associated with one sample tend to be greater than the weights in the other sample.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wx = rng.random(size=m)*2
wy = rng.random(size=n)
assess_size()
```

[image]

So you might consider performing the same assessment with your actual weights.

Because the test is conservative, the power (probability of correctly rejecting a false null hypothesis) of this approximation is a little low. If you want more accurate p-values, you can compute them using a Monte Carlo approach. To do this, we modify your function slightly so that it returns the `U` statistic instead of the p-value, and we use [`scipy.stats.monte_carlo_test`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.monte_carlo_test.html) to generate a p-value.

```py
def weighted_ranksum_statistic(x, y, wx, wy):
    U = 0
    for iy, weight_y in zip(y, wy):
        smaller = x < iy
        equal = x == iy

        sum_smaller = np.sum(wx[smaller] * weight_y)
        sum_equal = np.sum(wx[equal] * weight_y / 2)
        sum_tot = sum_smaller + sum_equal

        U += sum_tot
    
    nY = np.sum(wy)
    nX = np.sum(wx)

    mU = nY * nX / 2
    sigU = np.sqrt((nY * nX * (1 + nY + nX)) / 12)
    zU = (U - mU) / sigU
    return zU

# use weights from before
x = rng.random(m) - 0.3  # null is false, alternative is true 
y = rng.random(n)

res = weighted_ranksum_test(x, y, wx, wy)
# `alternative='greater'` here because, roughly, the statistic tends to be
# *greater* when the alternative hypothesis is true
ref = stats.monte_carlo_test((x, y), rvs=(rng.random, rng.random),
                             statistic=lambda x, y: weighted_ranksum_statistic(x, y, wx, wy),
                             alternative='greater')

# p-values are close, and p-values are small, providing evidence against the
# null in favor of the alternative
print(res, ref.pvalue)
# 0.03557664132002421 0.0338
```

Indeed, the null distribution of the test statistic is approximately standard normal, as approximated by `weighted_ranksum_test`.

```py
ax = plt.subplot()
z = np.linspace(-5, 5, 300)
ax.plot(z, stats.norm.pdf(z), label='normal approximation')
ax.hist(ref.null_distribution, bins=50, density=True, 
        label='Monte Carlo null distribution')
ax.legend(loc='lower right')
ax.set_xlabel('test statistic')
ax.set_ylabel('frequency/probability density')
ax.set_title('Monte Carlo null distribution vs normal approximation')
```

[image]

Agreement is good in this case, but as we saw above, it depends on the weights.

```py
wx *= 2
ref = stats.monte_carlo_test((x, y), rvs=(rng.random, rng.random),
                             statistic=lambda x, y: weighted_ranksum_statistic(x, y, wx, wy),
                             alternative='greater')
ax.plot(z, stats.norm.pdf(z), label='normal approximation')
ax.hist(ref.null_distribution, bins=50, density=True, 
        label='Monte Carlo null distribution')
ax.legend(loc='lower right')
ax.set_xlabel('test statistic')
ax.set_ylabel('frequency/probability density')
ax.set_title('Monte Carlo null distribution vs normal approximation')
```

[image]

So especially if the plots produced by `assess_size` above do not agree, I would trust the `monte_carlo_test` version.